# Calculation Logic Coming out Incorrect Wordpress Get Field

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have created a reviews widget that collects all the reviews on the website and then creates an aggregate rating via a calculation. It seemed to work perfectly fine with around 7 reviews and below however I recently added more to make it 13 and the calculation seems to now be incorrect and I am not sure why can anyone help?

**EDIT: Updated code to be outside of loop, did not resolve the issue.**

```
<?php 
    $post_args = array(
        'post_type' => 'review'
    );

    $title = apply_filters( 'widget_title', $instance['title'] );
    $code = apply_filters( 'widget_code', $instance['code'] );
    $desc = apply_filters( 'widget_desc', $instance['desc'] );
    $link = apply_filters( 'widget_link', $instance['link'] );

    $total_rating = 0; //Sets the total rating to 0
    $post_list = new wp_query( $post_args ); //collects reviews

    if( $post_list->have_posts() ) : while( $post_list->have_posts() ) : 
    $post_list->the_post(); //initiates reviews posts

    $all_ratings = get_field('review_score'); //collects all integers
    $total_rating += $all_ratings; //gets all integers and adds them together

    ?>

    <?php endwhile; endif; 
    $multiply = $total_rating * 20; //Multiply total rating by 20 for width
    $total_reviews = wp_count_posts( 'review' )->publish; //Counts published reviews
    $width = $multiply / $total_reviews; //Divides multiply by amount of review for accurate % width of div.
    $divide = number_format($total_rating / $total_reviews, 1); //Divides the total of all reviews by amount of reviews e.g. 2 Review both 5/5 = 10/2=5=Correct.
    wp_reset_query(); ?>
    <?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

**FYI - get_field('review_score'); is input as an integer for the review score.**

**EDIT: Displaying the code that displays the widget**

```
<aside class="widget widget_reviews">
        </span>
        <h3><?php echo $title; ?></h3>
        <?php if($width > 0) : ?>
        <div itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/Product">
            <meta itemprop="name" content="Regency Chauffeurs">
        <div itemprop="aggregateRating" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/AggregateRating">
            <meta itemprop="worstRating" content="1">
            <div class="average-reviews-base">
                <div class="average-reviews" style="width:<?php echo $width; ?>%"></div>
            </div>
            <span class="average-score-link"><span itemprop="ratingValue"><?php echo $divide; ?></span> / <span itemprop="bestRating">5</span> (From <a href="<?php echo $link; ?>" title="<?php echo $title; ?>"><span itemprop="reviewCount"><?php echo $total_reviews; ?></span> <?php if($total_reviews > 1) : ?>Reviews<?php else : ?>Review<?php endif;?></a>)</span>
        </div>
            <div class="review-desc">
                <p><?php echo $desc; ?></p>
                <p><a href="<?php echo $link; ?>" title="<?php echo $title; ?>" class="button"><?php echo $code; ?></a></p>
            </div>
        <?php else : ?>
        <div class="review-desc">
            <p>There is currently no reviews, if you would like to leave a review then please <a class="underline" href="<?php echo $link; ?>" title="review">click here</a>.</p>
            <p><a href="<?php echo $link; ?>" title="<?php echo $title; ?>" class="button">Leave A Review</a></p>
        </div>
        </div>
        <?php endif;?>
    </aside>
```

Below is an image to explain the width variable, the golden star BG is what is altered by the $width variable in order to give an accurate graphic of aggregate rating.

[image: Review Width]

Comment: what's with `$multiply = $total_rating * 20;`?

Comment: you aren't saving/displaying what you are calculating

Comment: Updated to show how it's displaying, the displaying works fine hence why I didn't originally add it. Multiply is used to calculate a width of a div % wise to overlay a coloured star e.g. if the rating is 4/5 the multiply = 80% and the div bg will cover 4 stars.

Comment: what part of the code is the rating calculation, your code is weird

Comment: Comments added to the code for your explanation. There is 2 calculations the width of the div to display the stars and also the aggregate rating of all reviews.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your calculation after the the loop, get only published reviews,change the `posts_per_page` param to -1 to get **all** the review posts

```
<?php 
        $post_args = array(
            'post_type' => 'review',
            'post_status'=>'publish',
            'posts_per_page'=> -1
        );

        $total_rating = 0; //Sets the total rating to 0
        $post_list = new wp_query( $post_args ); //collects reviews

        if( $post_list->have_posts() ) : while( $post_list->have_posts() ) : 
        $post_list->the_post(); //initiates reviews posts

        $all_ratings = get_field('review_score'); //collects all integers
        $total_rating += $all_ratings; //gets all integers and adds them together

    ?>

    <?php endwhile; endif; 

$multiply = $total_rating * 20; //Multiply total rating by 20 for width
        $total_reviews = wp_count_posts( 'review' )->publish; //Counts published reviews
        $width = $multiply / $total_reviews; //Divides multiply by amount of review for accurate % width of div.
        $divide = number_format($total_rating / $total_reviews, 1); //Divides the total of all reviews by amount of reviews e.g. 2 Review both 5/5 = 10/2=5=Correct.

wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this did not resolve the issue. Here's whats displayed: $width = 76%, $divide = 3.8, $total_reviews = 13. There is 13 reviews, all of which are 5 Star so the width should be 100% and the divide should be 5.

Comment: Still Displays $width = 76% and $divide = 3.8 unfortunately

Comment: 3,8 of 5 rating?

Comment: There is 13 reviews all are 5/5. This means the total rating = 65. 65/13=5=$divide. 65*20=1300/13=100%=$width. As you can see from these calculations it should display. 5.0 and 100%.

Comment: do a var_dump($total_reviews,$total_rating); and post the result here

Comment: Displays: string(2) "13" int(50). So the total rating isn't calculating properly as its at 50 not 65. Could this be the default 10 posts per page in the query that we need to override if so how would I do this as I cant currently remember? something to do with -1?

Comment: you mean `'posts_per_page'=> -1`?

Comment: Yeah, do you think that'll fix it? Since it works fine below 10 it looks like its capping at 10 reviews which is a custom post type so we need to edit the query to display all right? Just saw your edit, trying now.

Comment: Fixed! Thanks for your assistance, perhaps you would like to add a small description of what the issue was to your answer for anyone looking for assistance in the future!